# How to setup domains reselling store front (website)

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am Softlayer domains reseller (resellone.net)

I intend to setup my own website for selling domains that must have facilities:

1. Search domains availability
2. Register domains
3. Billing
4. Update prices if required
5. My own graphic design (Header & Footer)

Best regards

Comment: Build A website .....or higher someone to build one for you. Its like asking how can I build a website. Learn some  HTML/CSS/JS....and start building

Comment: perhaps you not read my question carefully. I said I am Softlayer reseller and they have specific API that we are using. Furthermore I clearly tagged my question as "Softlayer" so its not related to building website or HTML/CSS/JS but its purely question related to Softlayer and expecting to have their reply

Answer (score 0):

The SoftLayer API provides direct control over every aspect of SoftLayer services, as well as your SoftLayer customer account.
It means that support for Domains and Billing information is available.

Regarding updating prices and setting up your own graphic design is a job that should be done by yourself.

These are some links that could help you with your requirements.

http://sldn.softlayer.com/

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain

Nevertheless, you could submit a ticket to SoftLayer, so that they might provide you further assistance.

Comment: Is your API supports store front or domain registration website for your resellers? this is the main question? Furthermore, I added Ticket # 31656251 yesterday and they advised to ask API related questions in stackoverflow with tag "softlayer"